# Why do C++11 CAS operations take two pointer parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, compare-and-swap

Many of the C++11 CAS operations (e.g., `atomic_compare_exchange_weak`, `atomic_compare_exchange_strong`) take two pointers and a value, i.e., like this:

```
bool atomic_compare_exchange(T* pointer, T* expected,       // pseudodeclaration!
                             T desired);
```

In contrast, the CAS operations from Microsoft, gcc, and Intel all take one pointer and two values:

```
long InterlockedCompareExchange(long* pointer, long desired,       // Microsoft
                                long expected);

int __sync_bool_compare_and_swap (T* pointer, T expected,          // gcc and
                                  T desired);                      // Intel
```

Why do the C++11 CAS functions take two pointers and a value instead of what appears to be a more conventional one pointer and two values?

Comment: `__sync_bool_...` returns a *bool*.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The signature I showed I copied out of the Intel manual.  I assumed that gcc used the same signature.  I now see that it doesn't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The C++11 way is more useful: If the exchange fails, then `*expected` is *updated* to the new, current value. That makes it easy to use the function in a loop:

```
T value = x.load();
T newvalue = frob(value);

while (!atomic_compare_exchange(&x, &value, newvalue))
{
    newvalue = frob(value);
}
```

With the Microsoft signature, testing whether the operation succeeded is more cumbersome, and ditto for GCC's `__sync_type` version. With GCC's `__sync_bool`, you even need to perform another load each time the exchange fails.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you wouldn't have both though. In my use-case the C++ version is less useful. I want to wait until a variable has some value then I want to set it to a new value.

With GCC instrinsics:

```
while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&value, expected, desired)) { }
```

With C++11:

```
auto tmp = expected;
while (!value.compare_exchange_weak(tmp,desired)) 
{
  tmp = expected;
}
```