# How to implement Valois' Queue by C++11's CAS

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, compare-and-swap

I want to implement JD Valois' paper *Implementing Lock-Free Queues* by atomic CAS provided in C++11.

For example, Valois' algorithm defines an `Enqueue` function:

```
Enqueue(x) {
    q = new Record();
    q->value = x;
    q->next = NULL;

    do {
        p = tail;
    } while( ! CAS(p->next, NULL, q) ); // 1

    CAS(tail, p, q); // 2
}
```

And I wrote codes like this

```
struct Node {
    T * val;
    Node * next;
};
std::atomic<Node *> head, tail;

void enqueue(T * t) {
    Node * nd = new Node();
    nd->val = t;
    nd->next = nullptr;

    std::atomic<Node *> p;
    do {
        p = tail; // 1
    } while ( /* CAS1 */  ! std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&(p->next), nullptr, nd) );
    /* CAS2 */ std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&tail, p.load(), nd)
}
```

Then I found that the two cas functions `CAS1` and `CAS2` are used wrongly. For one reason, `p->next` is not a type of `std::atomic`, for another, the second argument `expected` of `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` requires a pointer. In the question [Why do C++11 CAS operations take two pointer parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043723/why-do-c11-cas-operations-take-two-pointer-parameters), the cas function will set `*expected` to current value, which causes a dereference of `nullptr`. Moreover, stmt 1, `p = tail` also fails, because atomic's `operator=` is deleted. So how can I implement a Lock-Free Queue according to JD Valois' paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described all problems correctly. The next step is only fix the code.

```
struct Node {
    T * val;
    std::atomic<Node *> next;
};
std::atomic<Node *> head, tail;

void enqueue(T * t) {
    Node * nd = new Node();
    nd->val = t;
    nd->next = nullptr;

    Node *p, *next;
    do {
        p = tail.load(); // 1
        next = nullptr;
    } while (/* CAS1 */ !std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&p->next, &next, nd));
    /* CAS2 */ std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&tail, &p, nd);
}
```